# CouchDB: user creation without authentication. standard behavior?

Tags: couchdb

Sorry for this rather yes/no question, but I haven't found the document that would clarify it, or I must have missed it [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html?highlight=security).
Is it standard behaviour that you can simply create a new user entry to a couchDB (without being an admin user) in the following way:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"name": "jan", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

I just tried it. It does work and create a new user. I was unsure wether this is intended or not (a server admin exists, so it's no admin-party).
Can this behaviour be limited/configured, to prevent unwanted mass-signups?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview):

> In addition, the _users database is now treated different from other
>   databases:
>
> ```
> An anonymous user can only create a new document.
> ```

So, **yes**, an anonymous (unauthenticated) user may create a new user in a CouchDB.

To configure/limit this behaviour you can modify the `validate_doc_update` function inside the `_design/_auth` design document, which already handles certain user creation limitations (see [official example](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions)). The check `!is_server_or_database_admin(userCtx, secObj)` already exists there. To allow only admins to add new users, you could:

```js
    throw({forbidden : 'Users can only be created by server or db admins in this specific CouchDB installation'})
```

At the beginning of that statement, to forbid any further action, when not authenticated as db admin.

The part in `validate_doc_update` then looks something like:

```js
//[… existing code …]
if(!is_server_or_database_admin(userCtx, secObj)) {
    throw({forbidden : 'Users can only be created by server or db admins in this specific CouchDB installation'})
    //[… existing code …] 
}
```

Refer to the [example (scroll to the bottom)](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) in the official documentation for more details.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent an anonymous user from creating new users in the "_users" database in CouchDB 2.2 open the Fauxton DB manager and click on the "_users" DB.

Click on the "Permissions" tab and set the "Users" to "admin" and "Roles" to "_admin".

Also set the "Members" to "admin" and the "Roles" to "_admin".

Save the file and you're good to go.

(thx to Eric and Chris at CouchDB Users)

Comment: Man, anymore details on how this actually works? When it comes to permission tab in the UI idk how to configure it. Your setup works but I am not sure how. What does admin mean in the Users tab and what other roles exist other than "_admin"?

Comment: It works pretty much the same as "users" and "roles" on regular databases.

To get a better idea of how users and roles work take a look at:

https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/recipes.md

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incorrect in suggesting that:

> "you can modify the validate_doc_update function inside the
>   _design/_auth design document"

This is not strictly true. CouchDB *will* allow you to modify the validate_doc_update function inside the _design/_auth design document, but **the content of the document will be reverted to its original state upon restarting CouchDB**. This means that, if your CouchDB is restarted, the changes will be lost.

> See the CouchDB documentation - 
>   http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#authentication-database:
>
> `There is a special design document _auth that cannot be modified`

The correct solution is to change the behaviour from within the CouchDB *local.ini* config file.

See https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/require_valid_user

> **require_valid_user**
>
> ```
> When this option is set to true, no requests are allowed from anonymous users. Everyone must be authenticated.
>
> [chttpd]
> require_valid_user = false
>
> [couch_httpd_auth]
> require_valid_user = false
> ```

Comment: I removed the "accepted answer" flag from my answer, since this answer and Bill Stephenson's answer seem more appropriate for todays CouchDB 3.x. Since I am not using CouchDB currently, I can't verify either though. 

I wrote my initial question, using CouchDB 1.x, today its 3.*. So the answers may be version dependent.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** sorry, this is not answering the question. I did not read it carefully enough.

The standard behaviour is "Admin Party" what means, if no initial admin is created (see below), everybody is admin. So to answer the question - yes.

CouchDB offers basic authentication mechanisms.

The documentation bit most important is this: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html?highlight=security#authentication-database. Users are stored in a authentication database and admins are stored in the local.ini file. To add an admin:

- find the local.ini file with running the command: `couchdb -c`
- open the local.ini file
- in the section `[admins]` uncomment the line `admin` and add a password in plain text
- relaunch CouchDB. Then, the password will be encrypted (check it with reopening local.ini)

You can fore sure also add a role `admin` to the users database but even though the name is the same, it is just another user.

Please see also http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/security.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's however not answering the question, as I explicitly stated that "a server admin exists, so it's no admin-party". I know *how* to create users and admin users. What I wanted to know is wether unauthenticated parties are allowed to create standard users via the REST-API (which worked on my side, but I was not sure if this is normal behaviour)

Comment: oh I am sorry - I completely oversaw this ...